# Running callbacks in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `Reminder` model that needs to calculate an important piece of data upon creation. I'm using the `before_create` callback for this purpose:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates      :next_send_time, presence: true

  before_create  :set_next_send_time

  def set_next_send_time
    self.next_send_time = calc_next_send_time
  end
end
```

The problem is, the callback doesn't seem to be running in my controller spec. The attribute is vital to the model and throughout the rest of my application's tests I will expect it to be calculated upon `create`.

The `reminders_controller#create` method is

```
def create
  respond_with Reminder.create(reminder_params)
end
```

and here's the `reminders_controller_spec`:

```
RSpec.describe Api::RemindersController do

  describe 'create' do

    it "should work" do

      post :create,
        reminder: {
          action: 'Call mom',
          frequency: 1,
          type: 'WeeklyReminder',
          day_of_week: 0,
          start_date: Date.new,
          time_of_day: '07:00:00',
          user_id: 1
        },
        format: :json

      reminders = Reminder.all
      expect(reminders.length).to eq(1)
    end

  end
end
```

If I inspect the response, the error is that `next_send_time` is null.

How can I get the Reminder's callback to run in my Rspec tests?

Comment: paste the code of the spec.

Comment: Is the controller response successful at all? Check response.status in your spec.

Comment: expect(response).to be_success also fails. response.status is 422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `before_create`, try `before_validation :set_next_time, on: :create`.

If the record doesn't pass validation, the callback wouldn't fire.

EDIT: Corrected the method name to `before_validation`.

Comment: No problem! Here's the order of callbacks and such: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4.0 you can use the `[TestAfterCommit][1]` gem.

If you're using Rails 5.0 it is built in: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458